# Print data from loop in a table

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a file with 4 columns and 4 rows looking like this

[image: file]

I imported the file and created a loop to get some stats for each column separately:

```
file= np.loadtxt('file.txt', skiprows=1)
list= (file[:,0], file[:,1], file[:,2],file[:,3])
for a in list:

    ra = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
    mean = np.mean(a)
    med = np.median(a)

    print('range', ra)
    print('mean', round(mean,1))
    print('med', round(med,1))
```

However this would return me something looking like this

```
('range', 3)
('mean', 2)
('median', 2)
('range', 4)
('mean', 3)
('median', 3)
('range', 3)
('mean', 3)
('median', 2)
('range', 3)
('mean', 3)
('median', 2)
```

My question is how do I print it in a table format for it to resemble this:

[image: table]

I am looking for very easy solutions. Thank you for any help

Comment: How's your HTML?

Comment: I need to do it in python :(

Comment: How's your printing out HTML commands in a python `print` statement?

Comment: Ironic, considering your name, but have you considered `pandas`?

Comment: oh its not in HTML, i just wanted to easily show how it looks like visually in my Ipython console.

Comment: I have not used pandas before. Could you give me some hints? :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas` if you want a labeled table:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep=" ")
   ...: pd.DataFrame({'mean':df.mean(), 'median':df.median(), 'range':df.max()-df.min()})
Out[1]: 
       mean  median  range
A  2.666667     1.0      5
B  2.666667     3.0      1
C  4.000000     4.0      0
D  5.000000     5.0      8
```